# "OCSP server has no status for the certificate" after Firefox upgrade

Tags: apache, firefox, ssl, ocsp

I have a problem with this site: https://shop.angst-pfister.ch/
With Firefox 19.0 everything was ok, but after upgrading to 19.0.2 I get this error message:

> The OCSP server has no status for the certificate. (Error code:
>   sec_error_ocsp_unknown_cert)

What can I do to solve this problem? The application runs on a JBoss 5.0 and Apache 2.2.16

I've found this so far:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslocsprespondertimeout
But this is only available for Apache 2.3 or later...

Comment: edited title to be more descriptive. Also, this may fit better on superuser, as it seems to be a client-side problem? If you think it's actually a programming/server configuration problem, you may want to add some more details.

Comment: Other users are having the same problem with Firefox 19.0.2, it's not just me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the problem of either the OCSP server that belongs to the CA or with the Firefox. As the server doesn't deal with OCSP (it's CA's job), you can do little about this besides possibly contacting the CA for assistance.

Comment: Yes, it was a problem of the CA...